# Make a div scrollable in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make only the bottom half of my page to be scrollable if the list of the elements I have there is longer than a value.

I have a `Scrollable` component, I add it into the render surrounding the div of the bottom half of my page but it doesn't work.

The only difference I see is when I minimize the page, the whole page gets scrollable.

My code looks like this:

```
 render() {
    return (
     ...
 <Scrollable>
    <div>
         <div className="bottom-half">My list</div>
         ... other stuff 
   </div>
 </Scrollable>

 ...
 );
}
```

The component is working fine for sure. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Is there any reason for not simply specifying `overflow-y` on in the CSS for `.bottom-half`? You will also need the max height to be enforced by some CSS.